# Does requests_oauthlib cache by default, and should I even cache?

Tags: python-3.x, caching, flask, requests-oauthlib

I'm authorizing people on my site with Discord. I don't want to spam their API however, does the .get method in requests_oauthlib cache the response so it doesn't send duplicate requests?
If not, any way to go about doing this and is it recommended to do so?

Thanks

Comment: currently i do not found  a way to do it. there is a module requests_cache, but this will only affect direcetly request and not the session object used in request_oauthlib - but if you switch to request and send the token from oauthlib manually you can archieve this with the downsite of token expire check: https://realpython.com/caching-external-api-requests/